# How to understand this derivation of Raoult's Law?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, evaporation

A derivation of Raoult's Law in a textbook is as follows:

[image]
[image]

I cannot follow the chain of arguments: Why should $p_{A0}=p_{B0}$ ?
A and B are basically two different substances, each of which has a different vapor pressure.

Looking into Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raoult%27s_law) we can find this image (which is actually often shown in the same context): Here $p = p_{A}+p_{B}$ is not constant at all but depends on $X_a, X_b$. So how is one to understand what is in the book? I'm completely lost...

EDIT:

Insert the result 5.171 into 5.167:
$\partial p_A/\partial x_B = -p_{A0}$

$\partial p_B/\partial x_B = -p_{B0} \cdot dx_A/dx_B = -p_{B0} \cdot (-1) = p_{B0}$

It follows automatically from 5.167:

$\partial p/\partial x_B = \partial  p_A / \partial x_B + \partial p_B / \partial x_B = p_{B0}-p_{A0} = 0 \rightarrow p_{B0}=p_{A0}$

This is what I mean: $p_{B0}=p_{A0}$ sounds irrational to me...

[image]

Comment: I think you are right and the book is wrong.

Comment: why can you say this so definitely? just asking...

Comment: You are interpreting it wrong. It does not say that p$_{A0}$ = p$_{B0}$. It says that the pressure above pure B is p$_{B0}$ and the pressure above pure A is p$_{A0}$. Further, the pressure above an ideal mixture is a linear combination of the two, weighted by composition.

Comment: @John Custer. It does say that  that the pressure above pure B is $p_{0}$ and that above pure 
 A is $p_{0}$, but it also quite clearly asserts that $p_{A0}=p_{B0}=p$ and that it not generally true.

Comment: @John Custer: See EDIT in my question: There I explained in simple detail  what I mean. In the meanwhile mike stone  mentioned the same...

Comment: @mikestone - that is not how I read it. 5.169 and 5.170 specify the boundary conditions. If it is all A, then the pressure is p$_{A0}$, and the partial pressure of B is zero. And vice versa, switching A for B. The total pressure $p$ above pure A is not said to be the same as the total pressure $p$ above pure B.

Comment: @mikestone - That said, given the difficulties in parsing, it is poorly written.

Comment: @John Custer: Normally I would agree to what you say regarding pure A and B. However,  by taking the math above seriously (what else should one do when this is part of a derivation), there is mathematically no other way than ending up finally with $p_{A0}=p_{B0}$.  I think it is not a question of poorly written text but a somehow "suspect" derivation.

Comment: What is the textbook? (I never understand why people quote content without giving the context-providing source.) Here, is there some context for the assumption that A and B are essentially identical? For example, perhaps the author doesn't yet want to introduce the [chemical potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_potential), which would otherwise enable a more rigorous derivation.

Comment: @Chemomechanics: It is from "Atmospheric Thermodynamics, C.F.Bohren, B.A.Albrecht, 1998"

Comment: @Chemomechanics, yes, indeed, here is a statement, that in an ideal solution A and B are essentially identical, except for their names. I have overseen this. But is that of any practical relevance? What about the graph I posted in my question: in this case pa0 and pb0 are not equal at all but Raoult's law seems to be valid anyway. If A and B are identical, isn't the argument above a bit "trivial" and lacks from any thermodynamic approach? It seems clear for me, that when A and B are not distinguishable, p does not depend on x, since pa and pb are pressures from the same substance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that what has been written is rather confusing.

I believe that the author's aim is to show that with two **ideal** species, $A$ and $B$, at a given temperature *the contribution to the total pressure for each of the species is proportional to the molar fraction of each of the species*.

In this context **ideal** means that the intermolecular forces between species $A$ molecules must be the same as the intermolecular forces between species $B$ molecules and so indeed $p^0_{\rm A} = p^0_{\rm B}$ in this example.
The radioactive maker was just there to be able to note the effect of changing the proportion of the two species, ie decreasing the proportion of the radioactive species $A$ and thus increasing the proportion of the stable species $B$ proportionality decreases the contribution to the total pressure of the radioactive species and increase the contribution to the total pressure of the stable species.

Having shown that proportionality, I assume that the author will extend the scope of using that relationship to species where the intermolecular force are not the same, ie $p^0_{\rm A} \ne p^0_{\rm B}$, but one species does not "interfere" with the other species as far as the contribution to the total pressure is concerned.
So if $p^0_{\rm A} > p^0_{\rm B}$ then in terms of contribution to the total pressure, species $A$ will have a larger "effect" than species $B$.
This leads to Raoult's law *The partial vapor pressure of a component in a mixture is equal to the vapor pressure of the pure component at that temperature multiplied by its mole fraction in the mixture*.